# Could someone explain the [*.testsettings] file and [Load test Run settings] in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, testing

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to do a Load test against a web application. My test project include the following tests, *myload.loadtest* are composed of *test1.webtest* and *test2.webtest*.

- test1.webtest
- test2.webtest
- myload.loadtest

There's a auto-generated ***Local.testsettings*** file in my solution, and I can add more ****.testsettings*** files. The Visual Studio says:

> "Test Settings determine how tests are
>   processed."

But there also a ***Run Settings*** in a Load Test file.

I am totally confused about the 2 settings. How are they meant to be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this guide answers your question.

[Configuring Load Test Run Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997552.aspx)